# Running windbg on crash minimized

Tags: windows, crash, windbg

I run a windbg script when my app crashes on the client's machine. I do it by setting AeDebug registry (see below) and it works, but then windbg pops up on the screen, and my impatient users close it before it finishes.

How can I do it, but launch windbg minimized, so users don't notice the windbg window?

I've tried:

- Using cdb.exe - it still pops a console window, which my users will still close
- wrapping windbg.exe with a cmd that runs `start /min /wait` - this does start windbg minimized, but as soon as I add the relevant command lines like `-p <pid>`, the `/min` ceases to work.

## How I currently do it

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Auto"="1"
"Debugger"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\Debuggers\\x64\\windbg.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld -g -Q -QS -QY -QSY -c '$$>< \"C:\\Program Files\\My program\\DebuggerCommands.txt\"'"
```

## My attempt with a wrapper cmd

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Auto"="1"
"Debugger"="cmd /C \"C:\\Program Files\\My program\\dbg.cmd\" %ld"
```

### dbg.cmd

```
start "" /min /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -p %1 -Q -QS -QY -QSY -c "$$>< %~dp0DebuggerCommands.txt"
```

Comment: "I run a windbg script when my app crashes on the client's machine." - Why? Why not simply take a crash dump and run the script later?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I'm also consider this - take a crash dump (using procdump?) and analyze later. The problem: It's hard to setup a separate process to analyze the dump on the client's machine, and I'm (probably) not allowed to take the dump itself out of the machine because of confidentiallity (medical application).

Comment: There is [WER LocalDumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps). And you seem to have WinDbg installed on that machine anyway, so you can analyze it via remote session

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of WER LocalDumps, and maybe I can use it instead of procdump. But unfortunately I don't get to connect to the machine remotely - I only get to look at (windbg-generated) logs created on the machine and extracted via some other mechanism.

Comment: Okay, run the script on the crash dump instead of a live process.